# list of lists not spilt correctly adding 2 items to appended dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I am trying to generate a dataframe with a column of urls from a list of lists read from a file. This is what I am trying:

```
one_df= pd.DataFrame()
with open(r"product_Url.txt", 'r') as infile:
    l = [x.split(',') for x in infile]
    for x in zip(*l):
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(x), columns=['url'])
        one_df = one_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    print(one_df)
    one_df.to_csv(outfile)
```

The problem with my output is that there are a few rows in my output with 2 urls that look like this (for example):

```
0, ['http://www.ex.com/prod1'
1, 'http://www.ex.com/prod2'
2, 'http://www.ex.com/prod3']['http://www.ex.com/prod25'
3, 'http://www.ex.com/prod43'['http://www.ex.com/prod99']
```

My original starting data read from the file looked like this (but with more urls):

```
[" ['https://www.ex.com/prod1', 'https://www.ex.com/prod2','https://www.ex.com/prod3']['https://www.ex.com/prod2','https://www.ex.com/prod3']['https://www.ex.com/prod25,'https://www.ex.com/prod43']['http://www.ex.com/prod99']"]
```

When I tried to read it directly from the file into the dataframe, I got an empty dataframe and one column for every url. Therefore, I tried generating the dataframe with a loop.

What do I need to do to get rid of these cases where I have 2 urls instead of 1 per row?

Comment: Get rid means, do you want to skip those?

Comment: I would like to have each url on one row. Instead of 2 urls on one row, each time there is one of these cases the urls should be in a separated into a different row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the efficient way, but looking at the example you provided following may work where `[`, `]` are replaced and `dataframe` is created:

```
one_df= pd.DataFrame()
with open("product_Url.txt", 'r') as infile:
    l = [x.replace(']', ',').replace("[",'').replace('"','').replace('\n','').strip().split(',') for x in infile]
    for x in zip(*l):
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(x), columns=['url'])
        one_df = one_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    one_df = one_df[one_df.url.str.len()>0] 
    print(one_df)
    one_df.to_csv(outfile)
```

Result:

```
                           url
0   'https://www.ex.com/prod1'
1   'https://www.ex.com/prod2'
2   'https://www.ex.com/prod3'
3   'https://www.ex.com/prod2'
4   'https://www.ex.com/prod3'
5   'https://www.ex.com/prod25
6  'https://www.ex.com/prod43'
7   'http://www.ex.com/prod99'
```

## Alternatively,

A little cleaner solution may be:

```
with open('product_Url.txt') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

all_data = [element.replace('[','').replace(']',',').strip().split(',') for element in data]

one_df = pd.DataFrame({'url':all_data[0]})
one_df = one_df[one_df.url.str.len()>0] 
one_df.to_csv(outfile)
```